# Keepalived configurations

Tags: debian, failover, debian-squeeze, configuration, keepalived

I installed **keepalived** on two firewalls to provide fail over. I'm not sure  if the following configurations are correct (see configurations below).

Sometimes I have problems to reach the websites which are behind the firewalls. I suspect that when **keepalived** runs on both firewalls, for a period of approximately one minute, the websites remain unreachable.. then the connection to the websites is recovered.

What could be the problem? Can it be that the **keepalived** are switching state (MASTER or SLAVE) constantly?

Firewall-2  runs in MASTER state.  When keepalived is started on **firewall-1** it jumps into BACKUP state.

Are there commands or tools like `ipvsadm` to check the real state of **keepalived**?

Configuration `keepalived.conf` on firwall-1

```
    root@firewall-1:/etc/keepalived# head -n100 keepalived.conf

    global_defs {
        router_id fw_1 
    }
    vrrp_sync_group loadbalancers {
        group {
            extern
            intern  
        }
    }
    vrrp_instance extern {
        state BACKUP
        priority 100 
        interface eth0.100
        garp_master_delay 5 
        virtual_router_id 40 
        advert_int 1
        authentication {
            auth_type AH 
            auth_pass xxxx
        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
            194.xx.xx.x1
            194.xx.xx.x2
            194.xx.xx.x3
            194.xx.xx.xx
            194.xx.xx.xx
            194.xx.xx.x7
        }
    }   
    vrrp_instance intern {
        state BACKUP
        priority 100 
        notify "/usr/local/sbin/restart_pound"
        interface eth0.200
        garp_master_delay 5 
        virtual_router_id 41 
        advert_int 1
        authentication {
            auth_type AH 
            auth_pass xxxx
        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
            192.168.100.1
            192.168.100.10
        }
    }
..........
..........
..........
```

Configuration `keepalived.conf`on firewall-2

```
    root@firewall-2:/opt# head -n100 /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

    global_defs {
        router_id fw_2 
    }
    vrrp_sync_group loadbalancers {
        group {
            extern
            intern  
        }
    }
    vrrp_instance extern {
        state MASTER 
        priority 200 
        interface eth1
        garp_master_delay 5 
        virtual_router_id 40 
        advert_int 1
        authentication {
            auth_type AH 
            auth_pass xxxx
        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
            194.xx.xx.x1
            194.xx.xx.x2
            194.xx.xx.x3
            194.xx.xx.xx
            194.xx.xx.xx
            194.xx.xx.x7
        }
    }   
    vrrp_instance intern {
        state MASTER
        priority 200
        notify "/usr/local/sbin/restart_pound"
        interface eth0.200
        garp_master_delay 5 
        virtual_router_id 41 
        advert_int 1
        authentication {
            auth_type AH 
            auth_pass xxxx
        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
            192.168.100.1
            192.168.100.10
        }
    }
   ........
   ........
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked about commands or tools to check the real state of `keepaived`. 
 Probably the best is to use:

```
tcpdump -i <interface> ‘ip proto 112’
```

You should see periodic messages from the master for all virtual router ids (vrid in the trave).

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `tcpdump -i <interface> 'ip proto 112'` and found that, unless I was on a keepalived system, it wouldn't be seen.  I had to become a member of the multicast group with `ip maddr add <multicast address>` before tcpdump would report the multicast.  If you are using unicast this isn't a problem.

Since my question I have found some things which may be helpful to others.  First, my experience is that keepalived starts in MASTER state regardless of configuration and transitions to its "steady state" in a few seconds.  This is critical if you're trying to run scripts on state change which affect the keepalived system, you may find both notify_master and the "steady state" notify_... script running simultaneously and colliding with one another.

Second, on newer systems `systemctl status keepalived` may show state if run soon enough after a state change (and intervening events haven't "scrolled it off").  `kill -USR1 <pid of keepalived>` will create /tmp/keepalived.data which reports keepalived's state and this is reliable if run after "steady state" is achieved.  Using this method was my solution to the colliding script problem - sleep long enough to achieve steady state then use `kill ...` followed by examining the file.